# Link in Process Builder chatter post

Tags: chatter, process-builder

I've created a workflow using the process builder and added a Chatter Post as an action. How Can I add a link to that post, a link which people can click and go to a SF record?

Comment: you mean link to chatter feed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to manually build up the required URL to the record that started the process.

[image]

Here I created the link as:

> https://na5.salesforce.com/{![Account].Id}

You will need to change the na5 subdomain in the URL to match your instance.

This appeared in the chatter post as a link that I could follow back to the originating Account.

[image]

Comment: But hardcoding the URL in the post defeats the purpose. I have to move the process from sandbox to production. This will not change the URL dunamically. There should be a dynamic solution to this problem.

Comment: @sam -- you might be able to use the ol' base URL formula trick: `LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement a solution for this, but it's a bit long to post it here in fullness. The bottom line is that I added some additional functionality to Salesforce `ConnectApiHelper` class to support linking to records using the new *Summer '18* class `ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegmentInput`. With this change you can now create hyperlinks simply by putting the record ID between the curly brackets likes so:

```
Hi {SOME_USER_ID}, your Opportunity {SOME_OPPORTUNITY_ID} has been updated.
```

I also implemented an `InvocableMethod` so that you can call it from `Process Builder` or `Flow`. The end result was that now I can create Chatter Posts like the one below directly from `Process Builder`:

[image]

You can find the code you need at [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/smukov/ConnectApiHelper), and the detailed instructions on how to use it [here at my blog post](http://smukov.github.io/blog/2018/08/11/Post-to-Chatter-from-Process-Builder-with-hyperlinks-to-records/).

Comment: Good blog post, but I couldn't get it to work in a Flow. I just need to get a live line to a Contact record -- ideally the Chatter post would have the Contact's name, not the ID. Any tips?

Comment: Hi @PatMcClellan__c, it should be straightforward. Try adding a `PostToChatterAction` to your flow and in the `Message` property write something like this: `Hello {{!My_Contact_Record_Id}}.`. In the `Subject Id` put a record ID where you want the chatter post to appear. It can even be the same `{!My_Contact_Record_Id}`. Let me know if you are still having troubles?

Comment: No, it doesn't put the link in -- just inserts the actual record id. "Hello from {0036A00000RPeqbQAD}". What I need is "Hello from Carole White" -- with a hyperlink on Carole White that leads to record 0036A00000RPeqbQAD in Contacts.

Comment: Hmm, I actually tried this last night before answering, and I got a nice hyperlink. Could it be that you are on Winter '19? Because the org I tried it on is still on Summer.

Comment: No, still Summer.

Comment: Not sure what's happening. A screenshot of the flow component might help. Otherwise I'll try deploying my code to a clean environment later in the day (or tomorrow) to confirm that everything works fine. Sorry for the inconveniences.